# Determine timestamp of replication of documents during live sync in Cloudant

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb, cloudant

Right now I have transaction syncs with clients that go offline and online frequently. This means that creation of a transaction document (when it goes into pouch) doesn't align with the point that it is entered into Couch.

Is there a way for me to tag these documents with a timestamp on confirmation of replication? I see there are advanced replication schedulers but the `completed` flag does not apply to live replication which is what we are using.

I have tried tagging the document before syncing it, but this doesn't account for issues of network delay or backend delay of replication. It simply is the time I started the sync of that document, there's no promise that it arrived at that point in CouchDB.

Comment: No, there's no way to do this. Doing so, would create an infinite loop with replication, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use an add-on like [spiegel](https://github.com/redgeoff/spiegel) (using on_change documents to call back to an [update function](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/3.0.0/ddocs/ddocs.html#update-functions)) or another (pouchdb?) client to observe the changes feed and add the timestamp of when it was available to that client from the couchdb (which might be a little delayed).

Such a client would be in danger of creating an infinite loop as @Flimzy indicated in the comments, unless it uses a rule to not re-update docs with existing timestamps so that it does not write when it is re-triggered by itself and therefore stops retriggering itself. Spiegel has support for such a rule and/or stopping an infinite loop could be part of an update function.